# Isolate web.config files for different SharePoint web applications?

Tags: development, iis

We're in SharePoint 2010 and using C#.

We've encountered and issue where we need to have separate web.config files for different web applications. The *base* web.config file that resides in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\[port #]\` can be unique per web application.

However, for the web.configs that reside in our application/virtual directories under the 14 hive, these are *shared* between web applications.

How can I isolate web.configs within the 14 hive between web applications?

Answer (score 2):

This page almost has it right:

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/12/where-is-sharepoint-webconfig.html

However, for whatever reason it's saying you'll find several of the web.config files in the 60 folder when, as you suppose correctly, they should be in the 14 hive (is this SP2013? I haven't gotten to use it yet). I'm just going to note the ones in the 14 hive below.

**web.config configuration file(s) for extending other virtual servers**
Local_Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG

**web.config file which defines configuration settings for the /_vti_bin virtual directory**
Local_Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

**web.config file which defines configuration settings for the /_layouts virtual directory**
Local_Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

**web.config configuration file for Central Administration pages.**
Local_Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\Locale_ID

Comment: SP2013 would be the 15 hive, so this is 2010. Thanks for the answer, but this isn't really what I'm looking for. The web.config files within the 14 hive are shared between web applications -- I'm looking for a way to isolate them. +1 for you anyway